# Java call function in .jar

Tags: java, android, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I have a crash in my java application.

It happens when I try to call a static method from a class implemented in .jar file.

Here the error :

```
02-28 15:38:55.712: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(323): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TOOLS.CLog
```

Here call to my function :

```
mylog=CLog.getInstance();
```

Here my class in .jar :

```
public class CLog implements iLog {
static private CLog m_instance=null;
public static iLog getInstance() {
    if (m_instance==null) {
        m_instance=new CLog();
    }
    return m_instance;
}
```

Some help please.

EDIT :

my classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: What is your classpath? Is CLog in your classpath?

Comment: @Nishant I think we can all see that for ourselves, thanks

Comment: @josh.trow yeah I realized my words are not nice. removing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the jar with TOOLS package in the libs/ directory, so that it gets deployed on to the device along with the other classes? The error does not come from classpath settings in Eclipse, but rather from the device, which does not find the class.

The default tooling will package the jar with your app automatically when it is in the libs/ folder.

Comment: Yes ! When I move `TOOLS.jar` to `libs/` folder it works ! How Can I make ant use my .jar in my original folder and not in `libs/` folder ?

Comment: You could enable the `-pre-build target` in build.xml to copy it from the original location to `libs/`.

Answer (score 1):

it should be (note package)

```
package TOOLS;
public class CLog implements iLog {
static private CLog m_instance=null;
public static iLog getInstance() {
    if (m_instance==null) {
        m_instance=new CLog();
    }
    return m_instance;
}
```

import class with fully qualified valid name

Comment: Yes of course I used `package TOOLS` and import it as `import TOOLS.CLog`. Here i put only some code lines...

Comment: and is this jar  in your classpath ??

Comment: yes, when I compile, jar is in my classpath, that's why I don't have error on my import. I have crash on run

Comment: thats it . . .! you need that jar in classpath @ runtime also.

Comment: I use ant to compile with `ant debug -lib C:\...\TOOLS.jar`. And I run my application with `adb.exe install C:\...\Application.apk`